# flex: border appearing when I mouse-over in datagrid containing skinnable container

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, mouseover

[image]I have a project where I display content from an array. I also need to display ratings- which is between 1- 5 stars

works fine with correct alternate shading for each line- **however**, when I mouse-over, the skinnable countainer in the itemrenderer(named cont) still retains the original color it had for that row. As we are using fxg graphics, we have a a skinnable container box containing the ratings with one shade, that lies just within the larger table - with row color having changed on mouse-over. Screenshot attached- you can see the thin patch of blue between the ratings box(dark grey) and the highlighed row on mouseover...

I was told to shift from Datagrid to List to resolve this and for better performance- seems like a biggish task which I messed up. As an easier alternative, was looking to 
I would like to **either**
a) get the skinnable container color to disappear, so I see single color in a row on mouseover
b) disable the color change on mouseover for the grid rows, so this issue is avoided

messed up previous entry- hence restating issue...

Thanks

The datagrid is very straighforward as below

```
<mx:DataGrid id="experimentgrid" fontSize="{12}"  fontWeight="bold" color="#006837" styleName="dataGridStyle" rowHeight="{15}" borderVisible="false" showHeaders="false" x="{20}" y="{50}"  width="{900}" height="{350}"   dataProvider="{arr_expList}" itemClick="onItemExp(event);" creationComplete="setColWidths()" verticalScrollPolicy="auto" verticalScrollBarStyleName="scrollStyle" >
     <mx:columns>
<mx:DataGridColumn id="col11" dataField="no"  resizable="true" />
<mx:DataGridColumn id="col12" dataField="Name" resizable="true" />
<mx:DataGridColumn id="col13"  dataField="Rating" itemRenderer="itemRenderers.experimentGriditemRender" resizable="true"/>      
</mx:columns>
```

The item renderer code is as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
focusEnabled="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import assets.graphics.dotrating;

            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.*;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;
            private var mydot:SpriteVisualElement;

            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {               
                if(value != null)
                {       
                    cont.removeAllElements();       
                    for(var i:int=0;i<value.Rating;i++)
                    {
                        mydot = new dotrating();
                    //600 is a stand-in for some calculations   
                        mydot.x= (600*0.02)+(i*600*0.02);
                        mydot.y= (600*0.012);
                        //mydot.x = (i*600*0.02);                       
                        mydot.height = 600*0.013;
                        mydot.width = 600*0.013;                        
                        cont.addElement(mydot);
                    }                   
                }
            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:SkinnableContainer id = "cont" top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0" height="{600*0.02}">

    </s:SkinnableContainer>
</s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>![enter image description here][2]
```

Comment: +1 for providing good code and not using binding in your itemRenderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want to set the [autoDrawBackground](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ItemRenderer.html#autoDrawBackground) property of the itemRenderer to false.  It s true by default.

Beyond that, you can try experimenting with the [rollOverColor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#styleSummary) style of the DataGrid.

Comment: Thanks- set autoDrawBackground="false" focusEnabled="false"- solved the immediate issue on hand

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I would definitely use a list with a custom item renderer instead of a datagrid.  Datagrids are heavy and have a lot of extra functionality that you aren't even using.  This would also solve your issue.